# How to pass a symbolic equation to constraints when using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

I have the following problem: When using `fmincon` I need to supply it with constraints. The constrain .M file looks like this:

```
function [c,ceq]=podmienky_L(qL)
global podmL zL
c=[podmL+0.0001-zL]
ceq=[];
```

zL is a constant while podmL is a symbolic variable that contains this expression:
(22.1*cos(qL(4))*(sin(qL(3))*(0.35*sin(qL(1))

When I try to run fmincon I get an error: `User function returned a complex value when evaluated;`

But when I replace the variable podmL with (22.1*cos(qL(4))*(sin(qL(3))*(0.35*sin(qL(1)) everything works fine.

The equation in podmL is supplied by another script and can wary from use to use and can attain hideous proportions, so it is very impractical for me to simply hardwrite it into the constraints function. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think if `podmL` is a symbolic expression then so is `c=[podmL+0.0001-zL]`, I'm not sure this is the intended use of symbolic expressions, can't you use an anonymous function?

Comment: I tried to use an anonymous function, but the result is the same.

Comment: The problem might be with how podmL is created. First I create a symbolic zeros matrix ant then I replace the zeros with symbolic functions. These functions contain variables l1, l2... .Now if I want to use fmincon I need to replace l1, l2 with qL(1), qL(2). So I used something like podmL=subs(podmL, l1, 'qL(1)'); to switch them. This might cause problems but I don't know how to make it differently.